# Why is this cast redundant in C#?

Tags: c#, enums, casting, integer, switch-statement

This is `OrderStatus` enum:

```
public enum OrderStatus
    {
        [Display(Name = "Gözləmədə")]
        Pending,
        [Display(Name = "Qəbul olundu")]
        Accepted,
        [Display(Name = "Ləğv edildi")]
        Rejected,
        [Display(Name = "Çatdırıldı")]
        Delivered
    }
```

This is `Order` model:

```
public class Order : BaseEntity
    {
        public string AppUserId { get; set; }
        public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        [StringLength(255), Required]
        public string StoreName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(255), Required]
        public string StoreAddress { get; set; }
        public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
        public double RemainingBalance { get; set; }
        public ShippingMethod ShippingMethod { get; set; }
        public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
        public PaymentStatus PaymentStatus { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
    }
```

And there is a `switch` statement in the `OrderController` to filter data:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> PaginateAsync(string status, int page)
        {
            ViewBag.Status = status;
            ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;
            int perPage = 10;
            ViewBag.PerPage = perPage;

            IEnumerable<Order> orders = await _context.Orders
                .Include(o => o.AppUser)
                .Include(o => o.OrderItems)
                .Where(o => !o.IsDeleted)
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.Id)
                .ToListAsync();

            orders = status switch
            {
                "pending" => orders.Where(o => (int)o.Status == 0),
                "accepted" => orders.Where(o => (int)o.Status == 1),
                "rejected" => orders.Where(o => (int)o.Status == 2),
                "delivered" => orders.Where(o => (int)o.Status == 3),
                _ => orders
            };

            ViewBag.PageCount = Math.Ceiling((double)orders.Count() / perPage);

            return orders.Skip((page - 1) * perPage).Take(perPage);
        }
```

My question is: Why is cast to integer redundant? I need to cast the values to `int` to compare them in `accepted`, `rejected`, and `delivered` cases, but not `pending` case. Why is it unnecessary in `pending` case?

[image]

Actually, this is just question, not a problem.

Comment: how does orders object look like? can you paste a sample?

Comment: enum will be implicitly casted to int, if compared to int, don’t need to cast explicitly

Comment: @RandRandom are you sure? [sharplab does not agree](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDIJYDsAuACV2C82AsgJ4Ci6ArgLYB0A8ugKYDcyUcAnABSkU0NmBQnACUbFEiZVqxcjOQBvZAEgAcgHtmAGlWMmupCoAqAdw3IAvkA=).

Comment: @GuruStron - fixed that for you https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDIJYDMAEAKAsgTwFEA7AVwFsA6AeWIFNMBeRzABgEpkBvZZAX14okdMuUwESFbsgCQAOQD29ADSzadVUhkAVAO4L+QA

Comment: I also added the `Order` model as image.

Comment: 1) Please do not post code as images (so users can copy-paste it) 2) seems like IDE bug

Comment: @RandRandom interesting. What is so special about `0`.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is cast to integer redundant

As you have noticed that not all casts are redundant but only a specific one - from `0`.

Found in the specification ["Implicit enumeration conversions" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1024-implicit-enumeration-conversions):

> An implicit enumeration conversion permits a `constant_expression` (§11.23) with any integer type **and the value zero** to be converted to any `enum_type` and to any `nullable_value_type` whose underlying type is an `enum_type`. In the latter case the conversion is evaluated by converting to the underlying `enum_type` and wrapping the result.

So there implicit conversion from `0` constant to your enum exists, so no explicit cast is required. Hence:

```cs
const byte bZero = 0; 
MyEnum me = bZero; // Compiles
MyEnum me1 = 0; // Compiles
// MyEnum me2 = 1; // Does not compile

enum MyEnum
{
    None = 10,
    One,
    Two
}
```

[Demo@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUHgYwHsoBnYAAgCMBPYAU2oC16wiKBeCgBgG4K8AWRoBRKBAC2FCYy5UWbfgHolFAMJEJABwCWAG3qkho8VJmZOPZao3b9hvCorCxk6fXSXM1igBEihhRQRJTEdgZ4ePSmziaSeADeeACQAHIkshSY3DApAPJQ9Lm4yQAqAO5EeAC+QA)

P.S.

Thanks to [@Rand Random](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2598770/rand-random) for the pointers.